# to be spelled as or to be spelled by?

Tags: grammar, orthography, prepositional-phrases

What is the correct preposition to use with the verb "to spell"? I'm trying to write a sentence "this sound is usually spelled by the letter "e". I'm not sure if I should say "**by** the letter "e" or "**a**s the letter "e". Or maybe both variants are not correct? :)

Comment: Neither of them sound right, (i'd probably use "with") but the concept of spelling a sound is a bit confusing.   Can you provide some more context please?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. The text I'm writing is about phonetics and spelling, after describing a sound, I have to give some information how this sound is usually represented in writing. For example, "the /æ/ sound is typically spelled as (?)/by (?)/with (?) the letter "a"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that "spelled" is the right verb here at all, as spelled describes a **word**.  I think you should say **written**, eg

*The /æ/ sound is typically written as "a" or "ah".*

Answer (score 3):

I would say "spelled with" as mentioned in a comment.  Or I would use no preposition at all.

> - exaggerated" is spelled with double "g".
> - there are a few words in English where the "g" sound is spelled "gg".

Google Ngram Viewer produces a few "spelled by" and "spelled as", though

Answer (score 2):

The letter “e” sound can be *short* as in ‘red’, *long* (as in scream), or *none/silent* (as in ‘done’).

A better way to say it is “this sound is usually spelled by the letter ‘e’ as in *red*/*scream*/*done* [or any other phonic sound of ‘e’].”